# using the say verb in twilio to say a phone number

Tags: php, twilio

I am using Twilio with php code as a phone card. The client presses their phone number and then it's dialed. Before it's dialed the voice says, "the number you have dial is..". But it says it as a number i.e. 9million, 776 thousand 8hundred and 94. I want it to say 9776894 etc.
It's a different number each time.( I have another part of the menu where it says, "you are calling home" and then dials it.)

I think it's to do with the "Request digests", but I'm not sure on the code. 
Thanks.

```
<?php
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<Response><Say>The Australian Phone Number you entered was"                 $_REQUEST['Digits'] . "
Transferring you now</Say>
<Dial>
<Number>+61"
.   $_REQUEST['Digits'] . 
"</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you put spaces in between the digits, Twilio should read them as distinct numbers.

Comment: And since it's php, try this simple method: `implode(' ', str_split('1234'))`